# display return value of new program in c using execvp in child process

Tags: c, fork

Working on a uni task where I need to use 1 parent process to create 3 child processes and then perform some calculations on each child process. I am stuck on child 2 where I need to load a program which returns the amount of words in a text file and displays it on the console.

This is my word count file:

**wc.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *wordCountFile = argv[1];
    printf("file name passed is %s\n",wordCountFile);
    printf("testing\n");
}
```

the file above does not actually count the words in a file yet as I am just working on getting it to display in the console

In my main program I have

```
child2 = fork();
        wordCountFile = argv[1];
        char *cmd = "wc";
        char *args[3];
        argv[0] = "wc";
        argv[1] = wordCountFile;
        argv[2] = NULL;
        if (child2 == 0){
            printf("I am child two my pid is %d \n",getpid());
            printf("I will now execute wc program to count all the words in file %s \n",wordCountFile);
            execvp(cmd, args);
            exit(3);
        }
```

my output is the following:

```
I am child two my pid is 659
I will now execute wc program to count all the words in file test.txt
```

I am trying to get the wc program to print to the console

I have compiled wc.c and the program is in the same directory as my main code.

Comment: If on Linux, you need to read books (on paper) like [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Comment: please, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be tested by us to be able to make a diagnostic. Edit your code, include the #include directives, a minimal main() routine and the variable declarations of the identifiers you use in your snippet. Or we would not be able to help you.

Comment: Why do you talk about child 2 if you create only one child in your snippet?  there's no 2nd child, for that you need to make a second `fork()` in the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your main program. you are modifying `argv` and passing `args` to `execvpe` and you are calling `wc` program not `./wc`. If you are in unix system you probably have `/usr/bin/wc`, and `execvpe` will call that program.

Correction to your main program

```
child2 = fork();
        wordCountFile = argv[1];
        char *cmd = "./wc";
        char *args[3];
        args[0] = "./wc";
        args[1] = wordCountFile;
        args[2] = NULL;
        if (child2 == 0){
            printf("I am child two my pid is %d \n",getpid());
            printf("I will now execute wc program to count all the words in file %s \n",wordCountFile);
            execvp(cmd, args);
            exit(3);
        }
```

Now main program will call `wc` program in current directory.